# Failed to GET matplotlib generated png in django

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, matplotlib, png

I want to serve matplotlib generated images with django.

If the image is a static png file, the following code works great:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def static_image_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')
    with open('test.png', 'rb') as f:
        response.write(f.read())
    return response
```

However, if the image is dynamically generated:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def dynamic_image_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(100))
    plt.savefig(response, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    return response
```

When accessing the url in Chrome (v36.0), the image will show up for a few seconds, then disappear and turn to the alt text. It seems that the browser doesn't know the image has already finished loading and waits until timeout. Checking with Chrome > Tools > Developer tools > Network supports this hypothesis: although the image appears after only about 1 sec, the status of the corresponding http request becomes "failed" after about 5 sec.

Note again, this strange phenomenon occurs only with the dynamically generated image, so it shouldn't be Chrome's problem (though it doesn't happen with IE or FireFox, presumably due to different rules in dealing with timeout requests).

---

To make it more tricky (i.e., hard to reproduce), it seems to be network speed dependent. It happens if I access the url from an IP in China, but not if via a proxy in the US (which seems to be faster visiting the host on which django is running)...

---

According to @HSquirrel, I tested writing the png into temporary disk file. Strangely, saving file with matplotlib didn't work,

```
plt.savefig('MPL.png', format='png')
with open('MPL.png', 'rb') as f:
    response.write(f.read())
```

while saving file with PIL worked:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
f = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(f, format='png')
f.seek(0)
im = Image.open(f)
im.save('PIL.png', 'PNG')
```

Attempt of getting rid of temp file failed:

```
im.save(response, 'PNG')
```

However, if I generate the image data stream with PIL rather than matplotlib, temporary disk file would be unnecessary. The following code works:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new('RGBA', (256,256), (0,255,0,255)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 
draw.line((100,100, 150,200), fill=128, width=3)
im.save(response, 'PNG')
```

Finally, `savefig(response, 'jepg')` has no problem at all.

Comment: In the last part of the question, when you say whether it worked or not to save the file, did you mean it worked with Chrome or did it give an error?

Comment: I meant it didn't work with Chrome.

Comment: @herrlich10 Hello, did you finally manage to solve this problem ?

Comment: @hhh Hi, unfortunately no. I end up using jpeg...

Comment: @herrlich10 Did you try to use `content_type` instead of `mimetype` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the image to disk and then returning that? (you can periodically clear your disk of such generated images based on their time of creation)

If that gives the same problem, it might be a problem with the way the png is generated. Than you could use some kind of image library (like PIL) to make sure all your png's are (re)generated in a way that works with all browsers.

EDIT:
I've checked the png you've linked and I've played around with it a bit, opening and saving it with different programs and with PIL. I get different binary data every time. It seems each program decides which chunks to keep and which to remove. They all encode the png image data differently as well (as far as I can see, I am by no means a specialist in this, I just looked at the binary data based on the specs).

There are a few different paths you can take:

1.The quick and dirty one:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
f = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(f, format='png')
f.seek(0)
im = Image.open(f)
tempfilename = generatetempfilename()
im.save(tempfilename, 'PNG')
with open(tempfilename, 'rb') as f:
    response.write(f.read())
```

2.Adapt how matplotlib makes PNG files (possibly by just using PIL for
    it as well). See
    http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib

3.If it's an option for you, use jpeg.

4.Figure out what's wrong with the PNG generated by matplotlib and fix
    it binary (I don't recommend this). You can use xxd (linux command: `xxd test.png`) to figure out how the files look in binary and then see how things go using the png spec: [overview](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html) [chunk spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html)

Comment: Hi, I've looked through the source code of matplotlib and I've found that it uses PIL for jpeg and tiff formats, but it uses a C implementation for png format.

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/src/_png.cpp. And it seems Chrome has had problems before with rendering png images. If possible, can you make an example png image created with matplotlib available?

Comment: A test png image rendered by matplotlib is attached (here)[https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5rr46jr8b6k53v/test.png].

Comment: Just updated my answer with some extra info based on what I could find out using your file.

Comment: Thanks~ I'm using jpeg for now.